# how to copy image that is attached over the worksheet and paste it in new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code that is used to copy the image from one worksheet and paste it on a new workbook.
My problem is that ' it works only if the image is attached within the range .i want the code that works **even if the image is attached over the worksheet**'.

Note : input file may contain's multiple image

My code is :

```
Set xlwbkinput = ActiveWorkbook
Set xlwbkoutput = Excel.Workbooks.Add

shtcountip = xlwbkinput.Sheets.Count
shtcountop = xlwbkoutput.Sheets.Count

If shtcountop < shtcountip Then
    For i = shtcountop To shtcountip + 1
            xlwbkoutput.Worksheets.Add After:=xlwbkoutput.Worksheets(xlwbkoutput.Worksheets.Count)
    Next i
End If


    For i = 1 To shtcountip 'it runs till the input workbook have the last sheet

        xlwbkinput.Worksheets(i).Activate
        xlwbkinput.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:AZ200").Copy 'here I'm copying input sheet 
        xlwbkoutput.Worksheets(i).Activate
        xlwbkoutput.Worksheets(i).Paste 'here I'm pasting in my new worksheet

    Next i
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: is the picture inserted as Picture ? or as Object and displayed as icon inside a cell ?

Comment: @shai the picture is inserted as a picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `For` loop below will iterate through all shapes in `xlwbkinput.Worksheets(1)` (which is the worksheet with index 1).

Then it checks if the current `Shape` (picture) cell position is larger then 1, which means it checks if the current picture's is positioned in any cell which starts from the 2nd row - you can easily modify that criteria.

```
Dim myPics As Shape

' loop through all shapes in Worksheets(1)
For Each myPics In xlwbkinput.Worksheets(1).Shapes
    If myPics.TopLeftCell.Row > 1 Then   ' check if current shape's row is larger than 1
        myPics.Copy '<-- copy the current picture
    End If
Next myPics
```

Comment: You might check that `myPics.Type = msoPicture` (13) to tell the difference between inserted pictures and other shapes

Answer (score 1):

Give the following approach a try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim picIn As Picture
Dim picOut As Picture
Dim wksInput As Worksheet
Dim wksOutput As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Set wksInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wksOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each picIn In wksInput.Pictures
    Set cht = wksInput.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, picIn.Width, picIn.Height)
    cht.Chart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0

    picIn.Copy
    cht.Chart.ChartArea.Select
    cht.Chart.Paste

    cht.Chart.Export Filename:=Environ("Temp") & "\someTempPicName.jpg", filtername:="JPG"
    Set picOut = wksOutput.Pictures.Insert(Environ("Temp") & "\tmpPic5022.jpg")
    picOut.Left = picIn.Left
    picOut.Top = picIn.Top

    cht.Delete
    Kill Environ("Temp") & "\someTempPicName.jpg"
Next picIn

End Sub
```

This solution uses the `worksheet.Pictures` collection to iterate through all pictures on a sheet. The easiest way would be to simply `.Copy` and `.Paste` these pictures from one sheet to another. Yet, this approach would neglect the location of each picture on the sheet. Assuming that you want you pictures not randomly located on you output sheet, the above code will also copy the location from the input sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the help,great suggestion.