# Excel image of cell range size

Tags: excel

Is there a way to keep the actual size of cell range image in Excel?

I have an image of cells from another sheet, based on formula ='SheetName'!$A1:$D10 but the size (especially the height) of this range changes depending on its content. Each time it changes I have to restore the image of this range manually.

Comment: host your picture inside another container. control size from there.

Comment: Thank you, cyboashu, but what exactly do you mean by another container?

Comment: I am guessing that @cyboashu is referring to the typical solution in VBA where you'd create a chart object first and then paste any picture into it. Here is a recent post I wrote in that respect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313241/how-to-copy-image-that-is-attached-over-the-worksheet-and-paste-it-in-new-worksh/42314131#42314131 So, basically with `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add 0, 0, 100, 100` in the direct window of the VBE you can create one and then put your picture inside to easily control and retain size.

Comment: Thank you, Ralph! Maybe there is a cleaner and better solution, without VBA possibly? :)

Comment: Without VBA: go to the `Insert` menu and select `Object`. On the `Create New` tab select `Microsoft Graph Chart` and then click `OK`. At this point there is a standard bar chart shown in that frame. Select the bar chart and then press `Del` on your keyboard to rid yourself of that graph within. But the outer frame of the bar chart will still be there. That's it.

Comment: ahh.. Just add a blank chart, insert a picture there and set your formula `='SheetName'!$A1:$D10` on that picture. @Ralph gave you steps for both ways VBA/ Non-VBA.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. The picture of cell range inside the chart object does not update after changing the values in pictured cells.